# Detecting point where two objects collide

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I'm totally beginner in Flash and Actionscript so sorry if my questuon is stupid.
I have to make a platform game - I'm planning to write something like Icy Tower - my character is jumping from one platform to another to get to the top of a tower of something. And here is my problem - I want to allow the character to jump onto a platform only from the top, but if he collides with whe platform from the bottom, or from the side, I want him to bounce (I hope you understand what I want mean).

So, to do something like that, I need to be able to detect where exactly do these two objects collide - the only solutions that comes to my mind is to keep the coordinates of every platform in some array and compare them with the characeter's position evertime he jumps, but it just doesn't seem right. Is there an better way to solve this problem?

I will be grateful for any advice.

PS. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of a game library like [flixel](http://flixel.org/), or [flashpunk](http://flashpunk.net/). They are both great.

Essentially, you will need to iterate over all objects that your character can collide with. You can make use of .hitTestObject() to roughly determine if your character is colliding with any of the objects. Thereafter you can then get the coordinates and dimensions of your character on the stage and compare them to the coordinates and dimensions of the hit object to determine directions.

So in psuedo code

```
for each (var platform:DisplayObject in platforms) {
    if (character.hitTestObject(platform)) {
        if (collideFromBottom || collideFromSide) { 
            // allow movement 
        }
        if (collideFromTop) { 
            // stop downward velocity 
        }
        break; // might as well, as you have detected the collision
    }
}
```

CollideFromBottom would be comparing the top of your character with the bottom of the platform. Remember that as Sprites, both player and platform have [x,y] properties and [width,height], allowing you to determine coordinates.

P.S. this question should have been asked at [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have one more question - is there a way to do it, when all platforms are a part of the same object (I have a movie clip object called "platforms" and it consists of multiple rectangles), or they must be separate?

Comment: And one more thing - what does exactly the DisplayObject.x mean ? (the x coordinate of left-top corner or what?)

Comment: DisplayObject.x is how many pixels from the left side relative to its parent, and DisplayObject.y is from the top, so a line from 0,0 to 100,100 would be a diagonal line drawn from top left corner got it?

Comment: You should be able to get hold of the rectangles within the movieclip by iterating through its children and making use of getChildAt() function. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html

Comment: DisplayObject.x and DisplayObject.y together form the origin point of the Object, relative to its container. Generally it is the top left coordinate, unless you draw something in the area x < 0  or y < 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use a Physics Engine like [Box2D](http://www.box2dflash.org/)(
behold the examples), instead of creating some hitTest colision based game from scratch.
The probability of you having serious code/design problems and leaving the project aside are big.

There's a lot of good tutorials on internet, here a good resource - Using Box2d to Create a Side Scrolling Game:

1. [Part 1](http://chrismweb.com/2011/05/04/using-box2d-to-create-a-side-scrolling-game-part-1-intro-and-setting-up-box2d/)
2. [Part 2](http://chrismweb.com/2011/06/01/using-box2d-to-create-a-side-scrolling-game-part-2-adding-keyboard-input-and-an-enemy/)